# Run shell command in python through subprocess and provide multiple inputs for authentication

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a shell command which I need to run through a python process. Basically, the shell command interacts with various systems, has automatic provision in case of failure, i.e. in case connection gets interrupted, it will reconnect to another instance automatically and continue execution but everytime it connects tp a new instance it will prompt for a password.

My python code looks like this

```
p1 = subprocess.run("some command",
                     shell=True,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                     universal_newlines=True)
success = p1.returncode == 0
```

My objective is to provide authentication password,everytime there is a password prompt.

```
password prompt string- "some_random_system_string password : XXXXXXXXXX"
```

I was looking at other answers where `subprocess.Popen` was advised, but I am not sure how to use `subprocess.Popen` or `subprocess.run` to input this password, and also capture the output.

The problem is that the command might get disconnected any random number of time. Please note, that key-based authentication is not an option here (if only it was, life would have been simpler)

Comment: Can you split up the shell command with password requests in-between when necessary?

Comment: The shell command is a single command which calls another utility/app. The app itself prompts for password in the shell whenever a failure is detected. I am currently automating this process, and hence my problem. The password can be entered once using subprocess.Popen, what not sure how to do this multiple times whenever prompted